# Unknown Authz provider with Shibboleth on Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-httpd, authentication

Currently I am dealing with the migration of a **PHP web application** from **Apache 2.2** to **Apache 2.4**. This application is SSO-enabled, by using **Shibboleth** in order to manage the authentication process.

The following `.htaccess` file is tuned to manage the authorization for Identity Classes:

```
SSLRequireSSL   # The modules only work using HTTPS
AuthType shibboleth
ShibRequireSession On
ShibExportAssertion Off

# Page can only be accessed by authenticated users
Require valid-user

# To restrict access to an Identity Class
# use the configuration line below.

#Require ADFS_IDENTITYCLASS "Trusted" "Registered" "Shared"
```

Apache is able to start correctly, but while trying to use the content under the `.htaccess` file above, an error occurs:

```
/var/www/myapp/SSO/RestrictedIdentityClass/.htaccess: Unknown Authz provider: ADFS_IDENTITYCLASS
```

Take into account that I also enabled the `mod_authz_core.so`, but the issue persists. Note also that I am using Microsoft ADFS as Identity Provider, and generally everything works fine.

Any suggestion to point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Shibboleth** syntax has been changed after the upgrade from **Apache 2.2** to **2.4**:

```
SSLRequireSSL   # The modules only work using HTTPS
AuthType shibboleth
ShibRequireSession On
ShibExportAssertion Off

# Page can only be accessed by authenticated users
Require valid-user

# To restrict access to an Identity Class
# use the configuration line below.

Require shib-attr ADFS_IDENTITYCLASS "Trusted" "Registered" "Shared"
```

I had to add `shib-attr` before the identity classes in order to run the authorization process.

Note: check that `mod_authz_core` is correctly loaded within your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Shibboleth module located in this path. /usr/lib64/shibboleth/mod_shib_24.so.
Just use LoadModule to point this using any .conf file. 
This 00-shib-global.conf not created by any package. 
Like,  cat conf.d/00-shib-global.conf.

LoadModule mod_shib /usr/lib64/shibboleth/mod_shib_24.so